# After submiting the text disappears jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

When I write some text in the input field. And want it displayed below the input field, when pressing the submit button it disappears. I don't know why.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MgnKB/)

HTML:

```
<textarea id ="comments" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/> 
            <div id="divComments"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
function addComment(name1) {

        var container = $('divComments');
        var inputs = container.find('label');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;

        var div = $('<div />');

        $('<label />', {
            id: 'comment' + id,
            text: name1
        }).appendTo(div);

        div.appendTo(container);     
    }

    $('#submit').click(function () {
        addComment($('#comments').val());
        $('#comments').val("");
    });
```

Comment: because you're clearing it `$('#comments').val("");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the `#` for id selector, change

```
var container = $('divComments');
```

to

```
var container = $('#divComments');
```

**[See the fixed demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/MgnKB/2/)**

Comment: Thank you :). I want to ask you is it possible to edit the text when it's displayed? And do you maybe have a solution for that?

Comment: @AdiT It's possible, depends on the requirement.

Comment: Even if I am using label to display the text?

Comment: @AdiT Nope, label can't be edited, a hint like when clicking on the label, change it to a textarea, turn back to a label when finishing editing.

Comment: @AdiT Do some research first buddy :)

Answer (score 2):

The selector for the `divComments` div is missing the `#` for the id selector.

```
function addComment(name1) {
    var container = $('#divComments');
    var inputs = container.find('label');
    var id = inputs.length + 1;
    var div = $('<div />');

    $('<label />', {
        id: 'comment' + id,
        text: name1
    }).appendTo(div);

    div.appendTo(container);
}

$('#submit').click(function () {
    addComment($('#comments').val());
    $('#comments').val("");
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgnKB/3/).

Comment: That is not my problem. The main Problem is the text can't be displayed below the input field.

Answer (score 1):

As well as fixing the following line to add a hash

```
    var container = $('#divComments');
```

you will also want to change the submit function:

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addComment($('#comments').val());
    $('#comments').val("");
});
```

This will stop the form actually been submitted (and reloading the page) - which is probably the reason for your text disappearing.  If you don't have a form surrounding your inputs then you don't need to bother with the second part of this answer.